# error: expected identifier or '(' before 'typedef'|

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

i'm working since a few weeks on the same project and never had this kind or error.
I got it now without touching to the concerned file, which is down there:

```
#ifndef DIJKSTRA_H_INCLUDED
#define DIJKSTRA_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INFINI 100000.0


typedef struct dij
{
    int ordre;
    float** adjacencePoids;
    float* l;
    int* pred;
}t_dij;

int choix_action();
int choix_sommet_depart();
int choix_sommet_arrivee();
t_dij* allouer_dijkstra();
t_dij* allouer_dijktra_durees();
t_dij* dijkstra();
void afficher_resultat();
void sauver_resultat();
void detruire_struc();
#endif // DIJKSTRA_H_INCLUDED
```

This code gives me this error (Compiler is MinGW)

```
Line 11 error: expected identifier or '(' before 'typedef'|
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you should declare the parameter types for your functions. For a function with no parameters, use `(void)`.

Comment: Did you change the compiler flags? In particular the C-standard this should adhere to?

Comment: thanks, i'll remind that

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Maybe there are some stray non-ASCII characterss in the file? Just try cut (from here) and paste (into an empty file). Or retype it.

Comment: no, how can i do this in codeblocks?

Comment: The file compiles as is ( [demo](http://ideone.com/FKfAtJ) ). There's something wrong in your environment.

Comment: Can you include the code where u try to access t_dij in your c file

Comment: I suspect the error lies in the file the header shown is included from, or in a file included just before this one.

Comment: And in the error message you quote: Is this `|` after `typedef` real, or ist a copy&paste error?

Comment: I wasn't able to answer to my own question, and the code is too long to put it in this comment

Comment: this header is the first and only included in the .c...

Comment: You were right alk, I finally found the problem! Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: @user3329325: I suggest posting a comment on the accepted answer explaining just what the problem was. Or perhaps you can narrow down your `.c` file to something very small that still reproduces the problem, and update the question to show that. (And if the `|` wasn't part of the actual error message, please edit your question and delete it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the error lies in the file the header shown is included from, or in a file included just before this one.